# VBS script for Robocopy of backups

Tags: vbscript

I have this one VBS script for rc of backups which is worked earlier but not now.

```
StrDatum = Day(Now) & "." & Month(Now) & "." & Year(Now)
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8
Const OverwriteExisting = True
StrRobocopyOptions= "/E /B /R:0 /W:0 /V /NP"
StrConfigFilePath = "C:\Tools\Backup\backupJobs.cfg"
StrRobocopyExePath = "C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\robocopy.exe"

strServerBackupPath = "\\midaserver\KNJIGOVODSTVO"
StrServweLogPath = "\\midaserver\KNJIGOVODSTVO\logs"
strComputer = "."

Set objShell = CreateObject ("wscript.shell")
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colComputer = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")

For Each objComputer in colComputer
    strComputerName = objComputer.Caption
Next




Set objFSO = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objReadConfFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile (StrConfigFilePath,ForReading)
"Set objRobocopyStatusWriter = objFSO.OpenTextFile (strServerBackupPath & "\\" & strComputerName & "\copy_status_tst.log",ForWriting,OverwriteExisting) 
objRobocopyStatusWriter.Write "Started > " & StrDatum & " > "
Do Until (objReadConfFile.AtEndOfStream = True)

strSourceFolder = Trim(objReadConfFile.ReadLine)
strCommand = StrRobocopyExePath & " " & StrRobocopyOptions & " " & """" & strSourceFolder & """" & " " & """" & strServerBackupPath & "\" & strComputerName & "\" & imeDira(strSourceFolder) & """"

Set objRobocopyLogWriter = objFSO.OpenTextFile (StrServweLogPath & "\" & strCompuerName & "-" & imeDira(strSourceFolder) & ".log" ,ForWriting,OverwriteExisting)

Set objScriptExec = objShell.Exec (strCommand)

    Do While Not objScriptExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
        strLinija = objScriptExec.StdOut.ReadLine
        objRobocopyLogWriter.WriteLine strLinija
    loop

strCommand = "" 
objRobocopyLogWriter.Close

Loop
objRobocopyStatusWriter.Write "Finished"
objRobocopyStatusWriter.Close
Function imeDira(putanja)
    arrSubIme = Split(putanja,"\")
    imeDira = arrSubIme(UBound(arrSubIme))
End Function
```

When I run it,  appers next error:

Script: \mida5\c$\Backup\BackupiListFolders.vbs
Line: 29
Char: 1
Error: Path not found
Code: 800A004C
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

Comment: Use the [`/log` parameter](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) instead of trying to emulate it.

Comment: hum, how, I don't understand you ?

Comment: `robocopy` can create a log by itself (see the documentation I linked to). There's no reason for you to do it manually. As for the error message you're getting: the script can't find the config file `C:\Tools\Backup\backupJobs.cfg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) do the logging for you.

```
Function qq(str)
  qq = """" & str & """"
End Function

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set sh  = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

src = "C:\source\folder"
dst = "\\server\share\target\folder"

logfile = "C:\path\to\your.log"

cmd = "robocopy.exe " & qq(src) & " " & qq(dst) & _
      " /e /b /r:0 /w:0 /v /np /log:" & qq(logfile)

status = sh.Run(cmd, 0, True)
If status = 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "Backup complete."
Else
  WScript.Echo "Backup failed."
End If
```